# Can I create an element that doesn't turn on scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css

We have floating panels that may be partially in screen. Can the window/body ignore it when it decides if scroll bar needs to show?

We do need scroll bar when other elements go outside of the window, but not this panel. So overflow:hidden on the body won't work.

Comment: Give overflow:hidden on the wrapper of the panel, not on the body.

Comment: yeah, put those panels in a wrapper, as @PSCoder suggests, and also make that wrapper, maybe, be underneath other elements and width and height = 100%

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you should just be able to say:

`body { overflow: auto; }`

If you wanted control on which access the element overflows on then try something like this:

`body { overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; }`

Answer (score 1):

Objects positioned relative to the viewport with `position: fixed` do not affect scrolling.

Comment: they also don't scroll with the page

Comment: Right. But that may not be a problem for an object that's meant to be a "floating panel".

Answer (score 1):

I have just put up an example to show the behavior. I have no clue on your layout though.

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="pnlContent left"><!-- put as much content as you want here it will put a scroll bar on the body as the content opverflows --> 
        <p>
        Why use Modernizr?
Taking advantage of cool new web technologies is great fun, until you have to support browsers that lag behind. Modernizr 

makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript and CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a 

feature or not. It’s perfect for doing progressive enhancement easily.

How it works
Modernizr runs quickly on page load to detect features; it then creates a JavaScript object with the results, and adds 

classes to the html element for you to key your CSS on. Modernizr supports dozens of tests, and optionally includes 

YepNope.js for conditional loading of external .js and .css resources.

            Check out the full list of features that Modernizr detects, or learn more about conditional resource loading 

with Modernizr.</P>
 </div>
 <div class="pnlWrapperNoOf right"> <!-- put as much content as you want here it will just be hidden --> 
        <div class="panel">
            <p>We have floating panels that may be partially in screen. Can the window/body ignore it when it decides if 

scroll bar needs to show?

                We do need scroll bar when other elements go outside of the window, but not this panel. So overflow:hidden 

on the body won't work.</p>
               <p>We have floating panels that may be partially in screen. Can the window/body ignore it when it decides if 

scroll bar needs to show?

                We do need scroll bar when other elements go outside of the window, but not this panel. So overflow:hidden 

on the body won't work.</p>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div
{
    border:1px solid #cecece;
}
div.pnlWrapperNoOf
{
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.left
{
    float:left;
    width:49%;
}
div.right
{
    float:right;
    width:49%;
}
```